# Twilio authorization token error for video calls in MERN stack

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to integrate video calling in my application using express and next js.

My app.js looks like this:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const AccessToken = require("twilio").jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;

// create the twilioClient
const twilioClient = require("twilio")(
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET,
    { accountSid: process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID }
);

const findOrCreateRoom = async (roomName) => {
    try {
    // see if the room exists already. If it doesn't, this will throw
    // error 20404.
    await twilioClient.video.v1.rooms(roomName).fetch();
    } catch (error) {
    // the room was not found, so create it
    if (error.code == 20404) {
        await twilioClient.video.v1.rooms.create({
        uniqueName: roomName,
        type: "go",
        });
    } else {
        // let other errors bubble up
        throw error;
    }
    }
};

const getAccessToken = (roomName) => {
    // create an access token
    const token = new AccessToken(
    process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET,
    // generate a random unique identity for this participant
    { identity: uuidv4() }
    );
    // create a video grant for this specific room
    const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({
    room: roomName,
    });

    // add the video grant
    token.addGrant(videoGrant);
    // serialize the token and return it
    return token.toJwt();
};

app.post("/join-room", async (req, res) => {
    // return 400 if the request has an empty body or no roomName
    if (!req.body || !req.body.roomName) {
    return res.status(400).send("Must include roomName argument.");
    }
    const roomName = req.body.roomName;
    // find or create a room with the given roomName
    findOrCreateRoom(roomName);
    // generate an Access Token for a participant in this room
    const token = getAccessToken(roomName);
    res.send({
    token: token,
    });
});
```

Next.js

```
// pages/video.js

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Video from "twilio-video";
import axios from "axios";

const VideoPage = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("test room!");
  const [localTracks, setLocalTracks] = useState([]);
  const [remoteParticipants, setRemoteParticipants] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch a token from your Express.js server
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/join-room", { roomName }).then((response) => {
      console.log("Token received: ", response.data.token);
      setToken(response.data.token);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      // Initialize Twilio Video SDK with the obtained token
      Video.connect(token, {
        name: roomName,
      })
        .then((room) => {
          // Save local tracks to state
          setLocalTracks([...Video.LocalVideoTrack.getAllTracks()]);

          // Subscribe to participant events
          room.on("participantConnected", (participant) => {
            setRemoteParticipants((prevParticipants) => [
              ...prevParticipants,
              participant,
            ]);
          });

          room.on("participantDisconnected", (participant) => {
            setRemoteParticipants((prevParticipants) =>
              prevParticipants.filter((p) => p !== participant)
            );
          });

          // Cleanup when component unmounts
          return () => {
            room.disconnect();
            setLocalTracks([]);
            setRemoteParticipants([]);
          };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error connecting to the room:", error);
        });
    }
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Video Calling Page</h1>
      <div id="local-video">
        {localTracks.map((track) => (
          <video
            key={track.sid}
            ref={(ref) => {
              if (ref) {
                track.attach(ref);
              }
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div id="remote-participants">
        {remoteParticipants.map((participant) => (
          <div key={participant.sid}>
            <h2>{participant.identity}</h2>
            <div>
              {Array.from(participant.tracks.values()).map((track) => (
                <video
                  key={track.sid}
                  ref={(ref) => {
                    if (ref) {
                      track.attach(ref);
                    }
                  }}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPage;
```

When I test the express endpoint I can see the token.
On the next.js side, I can also see the token in the console.

When I visit the frontend, my camera turns green for a moment, but it switches off, and I see the following in the console:

```
TwilioError 20151: The authorization with Token failed
```

How do I fix this?